# command to change text files encoding

Tags: bash, shell

Is there any way to change encoding for a lot of text files using command line (bash interpreter)?

To be precise I want to get paths to specific files using `path` and then change their encoding in shell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `for` to get the files. Use `iconv` to convert them.